# Is it possible/safe to execute an openMP-enabled child process with python subprocess?

Tags: python, fortran, subprocess, openmp, slurm

I have a fortran program compiled with openMP which I'd like to call from python. I was wondering if it is possible for subprocess.popen to execute the fortran executable, and have it make use of openMP multi-threading.

Here's a simple example of a python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import os

def run_test(path_to_exe, exe_name):

    statement = os.path.join(path_to_exe, exe_name)
    proc = subprocess.Popen([statement], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    out,err = proc.communicate()
                                                                                                                                  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_test("/my/directory", "fotran_program.out")
```

This script would be run on a multi-core machine so the fortran program could use multiple threads, with for example a slurm scheduler script like below

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -p my_clusters_queue
#SBATCH -J my_jobname
#SBATCH -o job_%A.out
#SBATCH -t 0-08:00
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=36

export OMP_NUM_THREADS=36
export OMP_STACKSIZE=32m
ulimit -s unlimited

./my_script.py
```

Comment: Presumably you have tried this and it isn't using multiple threads: can you show what output you do get from a minimal threaded Fortran program (along with the Fortran code)?

Comment: It should be safe regarding what the OpenMP code does. You should check the variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` is transmitted to the FORTRAN code. You can just do that by printing `omp_get_num_threads()` or by setting `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE`. Note that SLURM often bind threads to core which can prevent any parallel speed-up. You can bind threads to cores yourself using `OMP_PLACES` and `OMP_PROC_BIND`.